# How can I improve performance of 3D based web application for clients on Citrix environment?

Tags: javascript, 3d, citrix

We have been reported with mulitple issues for our Web based application by one of our client who has Citrix environments set up in their showroom.

It is the only client out of 100s raising the issues with Performance on our web application.

We have (Azure application insights both for Front end and Back end) enabled on our side, which also shows slowness in response time for particular requests (more on FE app insight and less on BO side). The client has also configured Datadog RUM in order to monitor the performance.

However, when we (Dev, QA, Perf analyst, Customer Support) try to reproduce the slowness on our end, we never see any issues with the web application.

What all things you will suggest to tackle the situation? The client account is now becoming too much critical to handle.

Please help me with the ideas you can share to identify the root cause of the issues particularly on Citrix environment.

We tried installing Datadog RUM, applicaiton insights, but it seems to be not that much useful on identifying the issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.